# Refresh a tab on shiny app based on new data selected on the other tab

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app which has several tabs.

In the first tab, I am selecting data from a sample dataset and save it to the server as a CSV file.

In the second tab, I read the CSV file and plot it.

My problem:
When I come back to the first tab and change the data and save it, the plot in the second tab doesn't refresh even by clicking on the second tab name.

I don't want to refresh the whole app as it is a big app and loading is an issue.

I also want tab two to be refreshed automatically only by selecting the tab.

Thanks for your help.

here is a simple example:

```
library(shiny)
dataDir <- "data"
load(file =file.path(dataDir, "dt_clean.RData"))
#dt_clean will load dt.clean object which has all the data, you can use any other data of your own to test the app

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("tab1",
               column(4,
                      selectInput(inputId = "months",
                                  label = "Date:",
                                  choices = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar"),
                                  selected = "Jan")
               ),
               column(4,
                      radioButtons(inputId = "TS_which", label = "Which kind of data?", 
                                   choices = list("All months" = 1, "One month" = 2), 
                                   selected = 2)
               ),
               column(4,
                      actionButton(inputId = "savedTS", label = "Save time series data")
               )
      ),
      tabPanel("tab2",
               plotOutput("ts_plot_lof")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  saveData <- function(dtTS) {

    #save csv and RData file for TS
    if(input$TS_which == 2){
      ptt <- input$months
      in.dt <- which(dtTS$dt == ptt)
      dt.clean.date <- dtTS[in.dt,]
    }else{
      dt.clean.date <- dtTS
    }

    fileName <- "ts_data.csv"
    # Write the file to the local system
    write.csv(
      x = dt.clean.date,
      file = paste0("responses/", fileName), 
      row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE
    )
  }

  loadData <- function() {
      file.n <- paste0("responses/", "ts_data.csv")
      dt_ts <- read.csv(file.n, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
      dt_ts
  }

  observeEvent(input$savedTS, {
    dt.ts <- TSdata()
    saveData(dt.ts)
  })

  TSdata <- reactive({
    if(input$TS_which == 2){
      ptt <- input$months
      in.dt <- which(dt.clean$dt == ptt)
      dt.clean.date <- dt.clean[in.dt,]
    }else{
      dt.clean.date <- dt.clean
    }
    return(dt.clean.date)
  })

  output$ts_plot_lof <- renderPlot({
    plot(loadData())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think you have to deal with `reactive` functions. Also, it will help if you post a reproducible example

Comment: @TheBiro is right. I have done such a shiny app and from your description it is not clear what you want. For instance, Do you want the selection to be row-based? Or does the selection happen because you apply a filter? What do you mean with selecting data? etc.pp.

Comment: @5th my question is not related to the data selection. Data selection is a simple filter by date. My question is how to refresh the plot when changing the data

Comment: replace `loadData()` with `TSdata()` and it ought to work. I you use `reactive` you need to use brackets as well, to load the data. Because `reactive` is your function. If it works you can delete the `loadData` and `saveData` functions

Comment: @5th Yes, this is the solution. I did it by using a reactive function and not loadData :)

Comment: If you have only one plot depending on your selection, then you actually do not need `reactive` either: I use the `reactive`-function only when I have more than one output which depends on my selection. Thus if you have only one plot, then I would advise to copy paste the calculations from the `reactive`-function into the `renderPlot`-function.

Comment: But I use 'reactive' function in other places in my application as well.